# AppJar already presses all buttons when using addButton

Tags: python, user-interface

So I wanted to use appJar, however whenever I use addButton, it just does what I only said it should do if the putton was pressed. Here is the code that matters for the problem:

```
app = gui("Leiterspiel")
app.addLabel("l1", "Simple Demo")
app.addButton("1", calculate(1))
app.addButton("2", calculate(2))
app.addButton("3", calculate(3))
app.go()
```

I can see in the console that calculate gets executed with the parameter of 1,2 and 3 instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters to `.addButton()` are incorrectly formatted.

You are actually calling the `.calculate()` function, and then passing the result to each button.

Instead, just pass a reference to the function to each button:

```
app = gui("Leiterspiel")
app.addLabel("l1", "Simple Demo")
app.addButton("1", calculate)
app.addButton("2", calculate)
app.addButton("3", calculate)
app.go()
```